# Confused about piping commands from find to commandX?

Tags: command-line, find, pipe

I have a script, `run.sh`, that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(find corpus/ -type f)
for i in $FILES
do
    ./individual.sh $i
done
```

It runs without problem.

I want to do away with the run script by piping each file from find to `./individual`.

I would think that I could just do:

```
find corpus/ -type f | ./individual.sh
```

But in trying that it just pipes in a file with file name "" (leading to an error).

What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: Something like `find corpus/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 ./individual.sh` would work. No particular reason to not use `-exec` for this though (seems simpler, though runtime should be very close)

Comment: Also [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724) for the proper way of looping over `find` results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use find's `-exec` option:

```
find corpus/ -type f -exec ./individual.sh {} \;
```

For each match that `find` finds, it'll execute individual.sh, replacing `{}` with the name of the file it found. `\;` is how you end an `exec` with find.

The reason your pipe doesn't work is that the output from find is being provided to `individual.sh` via STDIN, not as an argument. Your script would need to know to look for EITHER input, or arguments through STDIN to make use of this.

Comment: That solves my question so I am accepting. I have another question about find -exec however http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164036/using-find-exec-and-having-trouble-with-redirecting-standard-error