# Using find -exec and having trouble with redirecting standard error

Tags: shell-script, pipe, stderr

I have an `individual.sh` script that pipes standard error to a grep command, like this:

```
FOUND=$(tesseract "$i" out -psm 0 |& grep -ci 'Orientation in degrees: [^0]')
```

If I run the script like this I have no problems `./individual.sh filename`

But I want to pipe a bunch of files into the script. I am using this command to do so:

```
find corpus/ -type f -exec ./individual.sh {} \;
```

which is throwing this error from the line in individual.sh that redirects standard error.

```
./individual.sh: 7: ./individual.sh: Syntax error: "&" unexpected
```

How do I redirect standard error while using the find -exec option

Comment: What kind you shell you using? - try `ps $$` to figure out

Does you shell script contains the #!/bin/bash (in case if your shell is bash) in the first line.

In posix shell you should use `cmd1 2>&1 | grep something`

Comment: You would never have had that problem if you had just done `cmd1 2>&1 | cmd2`. fancy implementation-dependent syntax like `|&` is fine and good for interactive shells, but when scripting if you make it a habit to observe portability wherever possible, you might find you do a lot less debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're using `zsh`. Try adding as the first line of the file, `#!/usr/bin/zsh`.

Comment: Afsin may have it right. `|&` is only supported on bash 4+ and zsh. Which shell and version are you using to execute the find command, and do you have a shebang (`#!/bin/bash` for example) at the top of your individual.sh script?

Comment: @Omnipresence yeah, adding the shebang fixed it. Why is that? Can you explain?

Comment: I only have a guess. I am going to assume you're using bash greater than 4 (you can confirm with `bash --version`) but you're using something something else as your shell (ksh maybe, check using `ps $$` as gena2x mentioned). Before you started using find (in your previous question), you'd been using `run.sh` with a for loop. That `run.sh` has a `#!/bin/bash` at the start, so when `individual.sh` was run, you were already in a bash shell. Now that you're using the find command, `individual.sh` is executed in whatever shell you're already in, unless you change it with a #!